# FLS info at User Level

Tags: metadata-api, administration, appexchange, customization, fls

I want a sheet for Field Access which User might have got through Profile or permission Set; Also wants to see if for the field user has access to is available on page layout and not restricted through any Validation Rule.

have you come across any App Exchange Product which can provide me this info?
or Any Idea/approach to accomplish this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [This source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/user-access-visualization) would give you profile/permission set information, but not layouts or validation rules. The layout checks can viewed in Setup. The only one that would likely not be available are validation rules. There's no easy way to say if the field is blocked outright or blocked under certain conditions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Security Zen](https://securityzen.net/)?  This enables you to pull Profiles and Permission Sets by user.  In full disclosure, yes, I am associated with Security Zen.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you please share any Demo video for this?

Comment: Don't have any videos, but you can try the app just by downloading it from the Security Zen website.  This is a desktop application for Windows.  The free version let's you download multiple profiles/permission sets for multiple entities (objects, fields, etc.)  The paid version enables you to select which profiles and permission sets to download or display by specifying a user.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask the people of Application Perfection here:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ei6FwUAJ
They provide a powerful tool to check all kinds of security and privacy related features.

Comment: Thanks for reply, This App provides Info only at Profile level not on user Level.

Comment: Hey RKM im pretty sure that it allows permission sets as well and with the combination of permission sets and profile you can emulate the user level. I only had a demo some time ago, but if I remember correctly it does work on PSets.

Comment: That's right.. It provides Profile and Permission set level but not on User Level, As User may have a profile and multiple Permission Sets, so to figure out FLS manaully for User is cumbersome task.